# MessageResources.propertiesの値を取得出来ません

Tags: java, jsp, struts

現在のソースは、下記ソースの通りです。
メッセージリソースに登録しているものを、JSPのhtml:errorsタグで表示したいのですが、
表示することが出来ていない状況です。

ソースの内容は間違えていないように思うので、
MessageResources.propertiesの配置かなと考えていますが、
classes/hello/resources内に配置しており、strutsの記載と合致しているように思います。

現在はこれといった原因が分かっておりません。
解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

```js
MessageResources.properties　ソース

test = error1
```

```js
struts-config  ソース
～

<!-- ========================== Message Resources Definitions -->
  <message-resources parameter="hello.resources.MessageResources"/>

～
```

```js
action.java ソース

ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

ActionMessage msg = new ActionMessage("test");
errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, msg);

addErrors(request, errors);

return mapping.findForward("error");
```

```js
 JSPソース

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=Shift-JIS" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html"
  prefix="html" %>
<html:html>
  <head>
    <title>Who</title>
  </head>
<p><html:errors /></p>
  <html:form action="/hello">
    <table border="0">
      <tr><td>
        あなたの名前は？<br>
        <html:text property="name" size="20" maxlength="30" />です。
      </td></tr>
      <tr><td>
        <html:submit value="OK" />
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </html:form>
</html:html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実際に動作させてはいませんが、以下のようにすればよいはずです。

ActionErrorsクラスではなくActionMessagesクラスを使います。

```
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
```

を

```
ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();
```

に変えます。

次に`addErrors()`ではなく`saveErrors()`メソッドを呼ぶようにします。

```
addErrors(request, errors);
```

を

```
saveErrors(request, errors);
```

に変えます。

ActionErrorsクラスはvalidate関連で使わるのみで、Actionクラス内では利用しないようになっています。
`addErrors()`メソッドはActionMessagesやActionErrorsといった複数のメッセージを一気に追加するメソッドです。ここではエラーメッセージを保存したいので、`saveErrors()`メソッドの方を使います。